# When I turn on my pc only white screen appears

Tags: boot

When my device booted, no dell logo appeared only white screen. I tried pressing F2 and F12. No help[image]

Comment: Based on the image and your description, it looks like a hardware problem. If it affects the OEM logo, then it's probably not related to Ubuntu since Ubuntu has no control over that.

Comment: Your hardware appears to be broken.

Comment: I checked my router connection, it showed that my system is connected

Comment: That it boots and connects has nothing to do with the hardware problem with the screen and/or graphics. It should be obvious.

Comment: Can you attach an external monitor and see if that works?

Comment: Didn't help. Still the same